# ag-grid enterprise server side how to set agSetColumnFilter filter checkboxes

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid enterprise 20.2 using server side and have a column where I would like to use the agSetColumnFilter filter type.  The column and filter display fine, but when I go to check a filter checkbox it returns from filterModel empty and no checkboxes are changed.

```
        {
            headerName: 'header,
            field: 'field',
            width: 150,
            filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                values: (valuesParams) => {
                    const values = Object.entries(field_values).map(e => e[1].id);
                    valuesParams.success(values);
                },
            },
        },
```

I am guessing that there is a callback or something to update the filter (setModel?), but I have not been able to sort out what the API is.  Could someone let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in the software.  I changed to rowModelType="infinite" leaving almost everything else the same and it now works.